# Why is diffusion current in a diode inversely proportional to doping concentration in the case of forward bias?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In a diode at equilibrium, there are Pn holes on the n side of the junction. These are maintained by the dynamic equilibrium of diffusion due to holes = drift due to holes. When a forward bias is applied, the amount of holes diffusing increases. That is an extra amount of holes $ P_n . e^{V_d/V_t} $ found on the n side of the junction. Here  $ P_n = n_i^2 / N_d $ and depends on N side doping.

Why is it that the extra holes that flow is independent of the doping of on the P side. If P side hole concentration/cm3 is higher, shouldn't the concentration gradient be higher and hence diffusion current increase. However it is dependent on the N side hole concentration instead.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to understand the physical relevance of why the equation
$ P_e = P_n . (e^{V_d/V_t}  - 1) $   depends on Pn and not hole concentration on P side of junction.
 Here, 
$ P_e$  = excess holes flowing due to forward bias on n  region 
  $P_n$= holes on n side at equilibrium (no voltage applied) 
$N_d$ = N side doping concentration 
$n_i$ = intrinsic concentration 
$V_d$ = Forward Bias Voltage 
$V_t$ = Thermal Voltage

Comment: Can you fix your equations? Consider using subscripts like V_d so each quantity has only one symbol, and note that to put several symbols in an exponential you do e^{(V_d/V_t)} not just e^(V_d/V_t). I would do it myself but in some cases I don't actually know what the equation is supposed to be

Comment: @AXensen Thanks for the feedback and help, I've fixed the equations.